# Providing acces to issue tracker only in bitbuckets repository

Tags: bitbucket

Questions:

1. If I have a user group related to clients added to a repository with read access, would they be able to clone the repository on their local system?
2. If yes, what measures should I take to keep a group or user restricted to issue tracker only and not the code, means they should be able to create,update and close the issues but they should not be able to clone the repository, is there any way to do it, as I do not want the client to have access to the code until he has paid for the whole project.

Comment: I encountered this, too (years later). I want a few customers (or contract employees) to be able to work with Issues without them having access to the code. I ended up creating two repositories. One that only has Issues and a separate repository with Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitbucket's permissions do not support what you want to do](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-privacy-permissions-and-more-221449716.html).

1. Users with read access can clone the repository:

   > View, clone, and fork the repository code. All public repositories grant all Bitbucket Cloud users read permissions automatically. Read access on a repository also allows users to create issues, comment on issues, and edit wiki pages.
2. There is no configuration that permits users to create and freely browse issues while restricting read access to the repository. The most likely setting would be private repository / public issue tracker, but in this case access to the issue tracker for users without repository access is restricted:

   > Only users who have access to the private repository can create an issue. Other Bitbucket users and any Internet browser can view the issue tracker if you publish the URL.

There may be other services that support your requirements.

Comment: Just a thought: this one feature alone would help small shops minimize admin overhead. The fewer sites/account/passwords to manage, the fewer new UI's to learn etc, this all helps.

In my case: a new project, new git, new set of client employees and how beautifully succinct it would be to add n emails into a repo with issue-tracker permissions only, so that i can drop questions directly there rather than resorting to email etc.

This would seriously make my day.